# how to align more number of RadioButtons of a RadioGroup in multiple rows to fit/display in the device

Tags: android, radio-button, alignment, radio-group

The orientation of the Radio Group is horizontal. I am creating Radio Group and Radio Buttons Dynamically .  It is displaying the radio buttons with respect to the device screen size. How to align the Radio Buttons in multiple rows if they are in large number.

Many Thanks.

```
if (status.equals("success")) {

                            JSONArray jarry = jobj
                                    .getJSONArray("questions");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jarry.length(); i++) {


                                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(
                                        RajaAndroid.this);

                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                                JSONObject jo = jarry.getJSONObject(i);
                                // rg = new RadioGroup(RajaAndroid.this);

                                RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(
                                        RajaAndroid.this); // create the
                                                            // RadioGroup
                                rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);// or
                                // RadioGroup.VERTICAL

                                TextView textView = new TextView(
                                        RajaAndroid.this);
                                textView.setText(jo.getString("q_id")
                                        + ". " + jo.getString("question"));
                                textView.setTextColor(0xff0000ff);
                                textView.setTextSize(20);

                                layout.addView(textView, p);
                                layout.addView(rg, p);



                                JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("options");



                                for (int j = 0; j < ja.length(); j++) {

                                    JSONObject jo1 = ja.getJSONObject(j);

                                    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(
                                            RajaAndroid.this);

                                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(
                                            RajaAndroid.this);
                                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.excellent);
                                    Drawable  db = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                                    // are added to the radioGroup
                                    // instead of the layout
                                    rb.setText(jo1.getString("option_name"));
                                    rb.setTextColor(0xff000000);
                                    rb.setTextSize(18);

                                    rb.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(
                                            null, db, null, null);


                                    rb.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
                                    rb.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 5);
                                    rb.setOnClickListener(RajaAndroid.this);
                                    //rg.addView(iv, j);
                                    rg.addView(rb);




                                }

                            }

                        } else {

                            Alerts.alertWithOk(RajaAndroid.this,
                                    "No Questions found", "Ok");
                        }
```

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/2m8038p.png

Comment: For reference please check the link to have a view on the issue i am facing